# How to use Pandas to take multi year average in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I have a large data set with data from multiple locations (given in lat/long) over 80 years.  I am trying to calculate a 10 year average for both column a and b from each site for the entire span of the time frame. Below is a sample of of the data table.

```
     Lat       Long Year Month Day      a      b
46.90625 -115.46875 1950    01  01 0.0000 1.1335
46.90625 -115.46875 1950    01  02 0.0000 1.1276 
46.90625 -115.46875 1950    01  03 0.0000 1.1213
```

Here is a sample of what I have tried but keep getting lost on.

```
fname = output1
df = pandas.read_table(output1)  
lat_long_group = df.groupby(['Lat','Long','Year']).agg(['mean','count'])
monthly_average = lat_long_group.aggregate({'a':numpy.mean,
                                            'b': numpy.mean})
```

Comment: For starters, you probably want `'Lat','Long'` in your code instead of `'LatLong'`?  It's a little unclear what you are trying to do but you probably want some of the moving/rolling functions:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create a column based on Pandas Timestamps:

```
df = df.dropna()
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp('{year}-{month}-{day}'
                                .format(year=int(x.Year), 
                                        month=int(x.Month), 
                                        day=int(x.Day))), 
                      axis=1)
```

Next, set you location based on tuple pairs of Lat and Long.

```
df['Location'] = zip(df.Lat, df.Long)
```

Now, delete the redundant data.

```
df.drop(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Lat', 'Long'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

We can now pivot the data by date and location. Your new DataFrame is now indexed on the date:

```
df2 = df.pivot(index='date', columns='Location')
```

Swap the levels of the new columns (so that location is on top of the values).

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.swaplevel('Location', None)
```

Finally, use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to get the mean value of your data over ten year periods:

```
>>> df2.resample('10A', how='mean')  # 'A'=Annual, '10A'=TenYears
Location    (46.90625, -115.46875)          
                                 a         b
date                                        
1950-12-31                       0  1.127484
1960-12-31                       0  1.127467
1970-12-31                       0  1.127467
1980-12-31                       0  1.127467
1990-12-31                       0  1.127467
2000-12-31                       0  1.127467
2010-12-31                       0  1.127467
2020-12-31                       0  1.127467
2030-12-31                       0  1.127467
2040-12-31                       0  1.127452
```

I used identical data for 30k rows (except for the dates, of course), but you can see how the process would work.

Note that the data is broken into even ten year blocks, so you may have stubs in your data at both ends (e.g. if your data started in 1947 then the first period would only be 3-4 years.

Comment: This was super helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: With Python 3, you need to convert the zip result into a something that Pandas can use. For example, with `list()`. So, the step above would be: `df['Location'] = list(zip(df.Lat, df.Long))`.